# The Midwest, Great Lakes Earth

Tags: environment, climate, geography, weather

I live in northeastern Nebraska, and I had seen more than enough of tornadoes in my lifetime.  So in an alternate Earth, it is my hope to make some changes that would save my home from being another potential target for that spinning Reaper's scythe.

[image]

Marked here in red is a vast plateau that varies in elevation above sea level between 3600 and 15,000 feet.  To the west are the Pacific lowlands (that peninsula in Alaska shouldn't be there).  To the east are the Rocky Mountains, which, in this alternate Earth, is a singular spine of Tetons no taller than Denali (20,308 feet above sea level).  The brown Y on the Atlantic coast are the Appalachians, which hadn't changed much except that its tallest point is now 9,931 feet above sea level, the height of Yosemite's Cloud Rest.

The Great Lakes Area has its own set of differences.

[image]

Imagine that the entire basin has been flooded off into one megalake, Lake Agassiz, 1500 feet at the deepest.

Are these differences the key I needed to bar off Tornado Alley, or have I created something as bad, if not worse?  Will the Midwest still be prairie?

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions about "Great Lakes Earth", so I am wondering if or when we will see any output; stories, youtube videos, artwork....With all this work I am hoping to see some very interesting outputs.

Comment: "Stories"?  Where is the place you have in mind?

Comment: There are a wide range of magazines (both paper and virtual) for publishing short stories, or you could write a novel and try selling it through a publisher like Castalia House (http://www.castaliahouse.com) or self publish on Amazon. At any rate I am wondering what you are doing with all this work on Great Lakes Earth?

Comment: @Thucydides Is there any way I can message you in private?

Comment: You could provide an email address, or maybe take this to chat

Comment: @Thucydides  How do I move to Chat?  Unless it's not more private than SE.

Comment: I created a room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41596/great-lakes-earth

Answer (score 3):

Not likely to change anything.

The added mountain range and larger lake you specify wouldn't really change that much from what is already there.

Tornado alley is caused by the movement of three air masses as shown.

[image]

You would still have these air masses moving in similar ways causing the same types of weather.

Comment: Would the new-and-improved Rockies not divert the west two air masses?